# openlayers load vector tile from binary

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

I want to load a vector tile in binary format to openlayer and got hung up on the `tileLoadFunction`. I just don't seem to be able to set the data to the tile manually. I need to use the `tileLoadFunction` since an API key must be passed to the tile server for authentication. This is what I have so far:

```
    let http = HttpClient;

    let layer = new VectorTileLayer();
    layer.setSource(
      new VectorTileSource({
        format: new MVT(),
        url: 'TILE_SERVER_URL',
        tileLoadFunction: (tile, src) => {
          // set headers
          const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            accept: 'application/binary',
            'authentication_id': environment.auth_token,
          });
         
          // retrieve the tiles
          this.http
            .get(src, {
              headers: headers,
              responseType: 'blob',
            })
            .subscribe((data) => {
              if (data !== undefined) {
                console.log(data);
                let vector_tile = tile as VectorTile;
                const format = new MVT();
                // Setting the features as follows is not valid
                // vector_tile.setFeatures(format.readFeatures(data, {}));
              } else {
                tile.setState(TileState.ERROR);
              }
            });
        },
      })
    );
```

I tried to find similar examples but nothing pointed me in the right direction unfortunately.

Comment: A `tileLoadFunction` for MVT format needs to set a function loader, see the example in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_VectorTile-VectorTile.html

Comment: well look at the second example where no tile loader is assigned. The part of interest points down to `setFeatures` which is equivalent for both cases and where I'm not quite sure on how to read those features from the binary blob.

Comment: MVT internal coordinates are relative to the tile, you need the tile's extent in the tile grid to read the features correctly, as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop-custom-mvt.html

Comment: @BeatScherrer were you able to figure out how to do this? I am struggling with the same exact issue. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I was and can post an answer later during the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the main mistake was not to use the `blob` type but rather `arraybuffer` which lead to the following:

```
import MVT from 'ol/format/MVT';
import VectorTileLayer from 'ol/layer/VectorTile';
import VectorTileSource from 'ol/source/VectorTile';

    layer.setSource(
      new VectorTileSource({
        url: 'https://your-vector-tile-api/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf',
        format: new MVT(),
        tileLoadFunction: (tile: any, src) => {
          tile.setLoader(
            (extent: Extent, resolution: number, projection: Projection) => {
              // set headers
              const headers = new HttpHeaders({
                accept: 'application/binary'
              });

              this.http
                .get(src, {
                  headers: headers,
                  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                })
                .subscribe((data: any) => {
                  if (data !== undefined) {
                    const format = new MVT();

                    let features = format.readFeatures(data, {
                      extent: extent,
                      featureProjection: projection,
                    });
                    tile.setFeatures(features);
                    this.map.updateSize();
                  } else {
                    this.logger.error('error while loading features');
                    tile.setState(TileState.ERROR);
                  }
                });
            }
          );
        },
      })
    );
```